# Does continuity on a closed set imply boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a function whose partial derivatives are continuous on a closed set, is it true that the partial derivatives will be bounded on that closed set? 
My intuition tells me that it must be so since for them to be unbounded would require them to be "vertical" if they are continuous, at some point, which would be impossible. 
However, I am having difficulty proving it mathematically, and I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not unless the closed set is also bounded.

Comment: The set $\mathbb R$ is also closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For example, the function $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous over the entire real line, which is a closed set.  However, if a set $D$ is both closed and *bounded* (which implies compactness in $\mathbb{R}$), then continuity on $D$ implies boundedness.

---

In general, if $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $D$ is compact (which, in this setting, means both closed and bounded), then $f$ is bounded.  The proof is relatively straight-forward.

> Recall that in a more general setting, a set is *compact* if every open cover has a finite subcover.  That is, if $D$ is compact and $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a collection of open sets such that $D \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$, then there is a finite subcollection $\{U_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{K}$ such that $D \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{K} U_{n_k}$.
>
> **Theorem:** If $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $D$ is compact, then there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in D$.

*Proof:* For contradiction suppose that $f$ is unbounded.  By definition of continuity, the set
$$ U_n = f^{-1}((-n,n)) = \{ x : |f(x)| < n \} $$
is open.  Then
$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n)
\implies D \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} f((-n,n)) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n. $$
If $x \in D$, then $f(x) \in U_n$ for some $n$, which implies that $|f(x)| < n$.  But $D$ is compact, so there is a finite subcollection $\{U_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{K}$ which still covers $k$.  Define
$$ M := \max\{n_1, n_2, \dotsc, n_K\},$$
and observe that for any $x \in D$, we must have
\begin{equation*}
f(x) \in U_{n_k} \quad \text{for some $k \le K$}
\implies |f(x)| < n_k \le M.
\end{equation*}
Therefore $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Continuity in a CLOSED set DOES NOT imply boundedness:

$f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: You didn't say that. Only closed..... FORGET... It was a mistake in my answer...

Comment: @TitoEliatron Read your answer again...

Comment: I wrote bounded but I was thinking on CLOSED

Answer (score 1):

No. For example consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined  by $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f'(x)=2x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but not bounded.